# NumberFormatter to leave always 2 digits behind floating point

Tags: php, numberformatter

I have ended up with a little bit of an overkill here, but I just cannot seem how to nail it:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('lv_LV', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::DECIMAL_ALWAYS_SHOWN, 2);
```

What I am trying to achieve here is:

```
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| INPUT | ACTUAL | EXPECTED | VALID |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  5,77 |   5.77 |     5.77 | YES   |
|  5,20 |    5.2 |     5.20 | NO    |
|  5,00 |      5 |     5.00 | NO    |
|     0 |      0 |     0.00 | NO    |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
```

In short, I always want 2 digits behind the floating point.

How do I achieve this with PHP's [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$var = number_format(553,2);
echo $var
```

Where 553 is the number and 2 is the amount of decimal places to display. It will ouput

> 553,00

NumberFormatter has a way of dealing with currencies if this is what you are after
http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: money_format is removed in PHP8. Use NumberFormatter for such issues.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is correct, I am looking to provide clarification as to why the OP was not receiving the expected results with `NumberFormatter`.

`NumberFormatter::parse` will `output` a `float` and accepts a `string` argument in the specified locale format. Parse however does not format the output.
It is the equivalent of performing `echo (float) '5.20'; //(float) 5.2`

`NumberFormatter::format` will `output` a `string` in the specified locale format and accepts an `integer` or `float` argument.
It is the equivalent of performing `echo number_format(5.2, 2); //(string) "5.20"` However `number_format` uses default values as the fraction and thousands separators and they would need to be changed based on desired display rules.

`NumberFormatter` requires that you call the `parse` method prior to calling the `format` method, for it to convert the locale specific string value to the integer or float value equivalent and have a separate `NumberFormatter` for your desired output.

### Example https://3v4l.org/HRnQN

```
$lv = new \NumberFormatter('lv', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$lv->setAttribute($input::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2); //applies rounding during format

$en = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$en->setAttribute($output::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2); //applies rounding during format

foreach (['5,77', '5,20', '5,2', '5,00', '5', '0'] as $value) {
   $parsed = $lv->parse($value);
   var_dump($parsed); //convert locale string to float value
   var_dump($en->format($parsed)); //convert float to locale string
   var_dump($lv->format($parsed)); //convert float to locale string
   echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

**$lv::parse($value)**

```
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| Value |  Parse | EXPECTED | VALID |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  5,77 |   5.77 |     5.77 | YES   |
|  5,20 |    5.2 |      5.2 | YES   |
|   5,2 |    5.2 |      5.2 | YES   |
|  5,00 |      5 |        5 | YES   |
|     5 |      5 |        5 | YES   |
|     0 |      0 |        0 | YES   |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
```

**$en::format($parsed)**

```
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| Value | Format | EXPECTED | VALID |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  5,77 |   5.77 |     5.77 | YES   |
|  5,20 |   5.20 |     5.20 | YES   |
|   5,2 |   5.20 |     5.20 | YES   |
|  5,00 |   5.00 |     5.00 | YES   |
|     5 |   5.00 |     5.00 | YES   |
|     0 |   0.00 |     0.00 | YES   |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
```

**$lv::format($parsed)**

```
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| Value | Format | EXPECTED | VALID |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  5,77 |   5,77 |     5,77 | YES   |
|  5,20 |   5,20 |     5,20 | YES   |
|   5,2 |   5,20 |     5,20 | YES   |
|  5,00 |   5,00 |     5,00 | YES   |
|     5 |   5,00 |     5,00 | YES   |
|     0 |   0,00 |     0,00 | YES   |
+-------+--------+----------+-------+
```